# Factors of primorial of number

Tags: number-theory, primorial

Given $n\in\Bbb N$, we know that $\ln(n\#)\sim n$ where $n\#=\prod_{i=1}^{\pi(n)}p_i$ is primorial function with $p_i$ being $i$th prime while $\pi(n)$ being number of primes below $n$. How many distinct factors in range $[\frac{\sqrt{n\#}}2,\frac{3\sqrt{n\#}}2]$ does $n\#$ contain?

I think it is more simple than that. You have $\ln(n\#)\sim n$. We have $\pi(n)$ numbers atmost. Note that $\ln(n\#)-\ln(\frac{n}2\#)\sim n$. This implies if we seek products from primes from $n$ to $\frac{n}2$ we should have reasonable estimate. Number of primes from  $n$ to $\frac{n}2$ is $\pi(n)-\pi(\frac{n}2)\sim \frac{n}{\ln n}$. We seek to multiply half of these at a time to get an estimate of $\binom{\frac{n}{\ln n}}{\frac{n}{2\ln n}}\sim 2^{\frac{n}{\ln n}}\sqrt{\frac{2\ln n}{n\pi}}$.

Hence, we have atleast $ 2^{\frac{n}{\ln n}}\sqrt{\frac{2\ln n}{n\pi}}$ distinct factors in range $[\frac{\sqrt{n\#}}2,\frac{3\sqrt{n\#}}2]$. Is my estimate anything reasonable?

Comment: I really doubt that there is anything beyond obvious crude approximations available on this. ln(n#) is not even approximated very precisely, nor are prime gaps. An answer to this question would almost certainly follow more precise answers to these other simpler but related questions. This would basically come down to selecting about half the available primes and counting how many such selections have a product in the right range. That seems to require a much more precise idea of prime distribution than is currently available.

Comment: I think that it is interesting to think about each of these terms you are adding/subtracting, but I think my prior comment applies to all these situations.

Comment: Well, by crude I mean both not elegant and not precise. You have that ln(n#) is within n/(2ln(n)) of n for large n. You could use this to find a range of primorials that are factors of the desired form. You could take this as a really crude lower bound. You could improve this by looking at factors obtained by removing and adding primes from the elements of this primorial list. It really seems to just get more ugly from there. And that is what I mean by crude, you probably aren't going to find any very useful approximations.

Comment: My earlier comments applied to exact ranges providing approximations. If you are interested in rough ideas with no exact error bounds, then there are different approaches. However, one consideration which your proposed technique seems to lack is that the target interval is really tight. The top and bottom differ by a factor of 3. Think of trying to construct a factor one prime at a time. The primes will be on the order of n, so most paths through the prime factors will jump from below the interval to above it without producing a valid factor.

Comment: A really rough estimate is to look at the total number of factors (2^pi(n)), and assume that each factor has a logarithm with a random value in the range (0,n). The size of your interval mapped logarithmically is ln(3), so say each factor has a chance of ln(3)/n of being valid. Then ln(3)/n*2^pi(n) is a really, really rough estimate. Note, however, that there are only 2^pi(n) possible factors, so your estimate is high.

Comment: $2^{\pi(n)}\sim2^{n\ln n}\sim n^n$. So it seems my lower bound is lower than your $2^{\pi(n)}$ since I am dividing this by $\sqrt{\frac{n\ln n}2}$?

Comment: Your estimate needs to be significantly less than the total number of factors, $2^{\pi(n)}$. $n^n$ is enormous compared to $2^n$, and the factor you divide by is quite small. So your estimate is way too high. Try plugging in n=20. Your estimate is way more than the total number of factors available.

Comment: Could you post your estimates as a detailed calculations in solution section?

Comment: $\frac{2^{\pi(n)}}{\sqrt{\frac{n\ln n}{2}}}\ll2^{\pi(n)}.$

Comment: I am going on the last line in your question, where the numerator is $n^n$, not $2^{\pi(n)}$. Either way, that factor you are dividing by is tiny compared to $2^{\pi(n)}$, so that estimate will be way to high. You are trying to hit a range that is about a ratio of ln$(3)/n$ to the total range of factors. The vast majority of factors will miss that range for large $n$. So the actual number of valid factors will be much smaller than $2^{\pi(n)}$, even on a multiplicative scale.

Comment: Think about some examples. $2^{\pi(20)}=256$, while $20^{20}$ is about $10^{26}$. Those two functions are quite different.

Comment: Please recheck. Have corrected error

Comment: $2^{n/ln(n)}$ is approximately $2^{\pi(n)}$, which is the total number of factors. So multiplying this by anything thats not really small will be an overestimate.

Comment: The denominator will probably be approximately linear, while yours is larger than inverse square root.

Comment: I think the major problem with your approximation is that you are not considering the difficulty of a factor hitting such a small range of values. That is a dominant characteristic of the problem. Without considering that, you will not get a reliable estimate.

Answer (score 0):

A really rough estimate is to look at the total number of factors ($2^{\pi(n)}$), and assume that each factor has a logarithm with a random value in the range $(0,n)$. The size of your interval mapped logarithmically is $\ln(3)$, so say each factor has a chance of $ln(3)/n$ of being valid. Then $\frac{\ln(3)}n 2^{\pi(n)}$ is a really, really rough estimate. Note, however, that there are only $2^{\pi(n)}$ possible factors, so this is a trivial upper bound.

As far as more precise estimates are concerned, we do not even know enough about prime distribution to get very satisfactory results on estimating $\ln(n\#)$ or prime gaps, so there does not seem to be much hope for an estimate with an exact range or an estimate that is very accurate at all.

Comment: The total number of factors is $2^{\pi(n)}$, which can be approximated by $2^{n/ln(n)}$, so $2^n$ is far over the total number of factors, let alone the small portion that satisfy your condition. A decent lower bound is going to be really hard to establish, and probably beyond the current capabilities of number theory.

Comment: Please recheck corrected question above.